# inserting the value in to a perticular node in xml file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xml-parsing

i have got the problem in inserting a value in to xml can you help me with that please. i am new to iPhone development in my situation i have got the xml like .....

```
 <Group name="ElectroFusionBoxData">
        <item name="ElectroFusionAcquire" type="Barcode" usereditable="Y" description="Start ElectroFusionBox data" minquantity="1" maxquantity="1" allowedvalues="">XXXXXXX<actualvalues />
        </item>
        <item name="WeldNumber" type="Integer" usereditable="Y" description="Weldnumber for the day" minquantity="1" maxquantity="1" allowedvalues="">XXXXXXXX<actualvalues />
        </item>
   </Group>
```

from the above xml i parsed the two elements and displayed in a tableview  that are "ElectroFusionAcquire" and  "WeldNumber" for those two fields i created two textfields . when i the user entered data in to those textfields that text needs to be save in the PLACE OF "XXXXXXXX" above xml could you please suggest me the way to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using `NSXMLParser` for parsing XML, which is only a read only parser. For writing/modifying XML you need to use some other parser like `GDataXML` or `TouchXML`. 
Also you will need to use XPath queries for accessing the particular node and updating its values

Comment: Thank you Devang. yes i am using NSXMLparser for parsing XML.i have gone through the GDataXml tutorial which is creating a new xml or new node .but it is not updating in to the existing xml value.and could you to tell me how to achieve this XPath queries for accessing the particular node and updating its values

Comment: Check out the article in http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml